# Position div next to vertical navigation in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put a div to the right side of a vertical navigation in Bootstrap 4 without success:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="nav navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some cool thing</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Some menu entry</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of .nav -->

  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills col-md-5">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Something</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 border">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the nav and the div to the right (the border is barely visible) extend further than they should and are wider than the navbar on top:

[image: screenshot]

[Here](https://codepen.io/justkidding/pen/ypGRbo) is a CodePen which demonstrates the problem. Is there any way around this using built-in Bootstrap classes? If not, how can I fix this manually?

If I don't use the `<div class="row">` and just put the components into the `<div class="container">`, the boundaries are correct, but they are not in a row anymore but below each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `navbar` instead of a `nav` at the top. Also the 2nd nav should be inside a col (not the column itself).

https://www.codeply.com/go/Q0lwszuHrv

```
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some cool thing</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Some menu entry</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of .nav -->

    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Something</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 border">
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When viewing your codeply, the div extends further to the right than the navbar.

Comment: You're welcome. It appears to extend further because the border is on the column instead of the content of the column. Try putting the border on the H1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, you should put a `.container` *inside* the `.nav`, not outside of it. This allows the `.nav` to be full-width. Then use a second container for what comes after.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some cool thing</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Some menu entry</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of .nav -->

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills col-md-5">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Something</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 border">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both have been very helpful, and sadly, I can only accept one, but I used a combination of both solutions! Have my upvote :)